# How to start a test server in dropwizard application using TestServer class?

Tags: json, testing, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard application with a single resource. The resource is hosted on the server in form of JSON. I want to test the JSON created by dropwizard application by hosting a test server using TestServer Class of Dropwizard testing. So, I need to know how to stop/start a server using TestServer class in a dropwizard application. And I need to do it during test phase only no other alternative way.

Comment: I suppose you are aware of the "Resource Testing" and "integration Testing" approaches that DW offers? If so, could you please clarify why the given scenarios do not apply in your case? What is "the Unit" you are trying to test?
https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/manual/testing.html#integrated-testing